# Edit tooltip to make it touch-mobile and responsive with just CSS?

Tags: css, tooltip

I managed how to create a css3 tooltip that works pretty well but can't work on touch devices (mobile) and which is not responsive at all...

This is the link : https://jsfiddle.net/zo13quf3/1/

```
<span class="tool" data-tip="Hyper Text Makeup Language">HTML</span>



.tool {
  cursor : help;
  position : relative;
}

.tool::before, .tool::after {
  position : absolute;
  left : 50%;
  opacity : 0;
  z-index: -100;
}

.tool:hover::before, .tool:focus::before, .tool:hover::after, .tool:focus::after {
  opacity : 1;
  z-index: 100;
}

.tool::before {
  border-style : solid;
  border-width : 1em .75em 0 .75em;
  border-color : #3e474f transparent transparent transparent;
  bottom : 100%;
  margin-left : -.5em;
  content : " ";
}

.tool::after {
  background : #3e474f;
  border-radius : .25em;
  bottom : 180%;
  color : white;
  width : 17.5em;
  padding: 1em;
  margin-left : -8.75em;
  content : attr(data-tip);
}
```

Is it possible to make it mobile-touch and responsive with just CSS3 ?
If no, do you know what i have to do to make this with the smallest js code ?

Thanks
Kind Regards

Comment: Hover doesn't work on mobile, but clicking the element simulates hover on mobile. This should work if you click the element.

Comment: Thanks, works but how to make it responsive too ? thanks

Comment: Clicking on an anchor with `href="#"` will indeed scroll up to the top of the page. If you want to prevent this behavior, either remove the `href` or add this to your js code: `$("a[href='#']").on('click', function(e){e.preventDefault();});`. (requires jQuery)

Comment: Yeah sorry, i just found this before your comment and edited this hoping you haven't seen it sorry for the time :s

Comment: And what do you mean by "make it responsive"?

Comment: For example with this [link](https://jsfiddle.net/zo13quf3/7/) as you can see the text in the tooltip exceeds the screen when it's at the right or left of the screen :/ ; make the width of the tooltip adaptative with the size of the screen, responsive

Comment: Yeah, bootstrap does this. They use a plugin called Popper. It puts the tooltip in the page according to the screen position, etc. It's quite dificult to do this trough css only, since css can't know the current position of the element. You can position it absolutely in the page.

Comment: Ok ! Thanks for these answers guy :p unfortunatly it's on a wordpress theme not using Bootstrap :/ , will try some tweaks thanks !

Comment: @Playzare Did you happen to find a solution? Please share.